# Postfix and sending incoming emails to script instead of sending

Tags: postfix-mta, mail-server

I want to use Postfix to accept incoming emails and have it send them to an external Python script which parse them and add them to a database.

I read that this could be done via a Policy file.

My first question is what should the policy file return to have Postfix delete the email from the queue with a success message to the sender.

My second question is can I use the Policy file to validate the SMTP authentication that was sent by the client? If not, is there any way of having it use an external script to validate the login?

Thanks!

- Christian

Comment: While you are sending it to Python, the crux of the question is still sys admin related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need SMTP authentication anyway and just want a script to act as [MDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent), I think you can do it simply by
setting `mailbox_command = /path/to/my/script` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and configuring an authentication scheme. If you have `dovecot` running, too, I can recommend having `postfix` authenticate via `dovecot`, which is very configurable when it comes to SASL authentication.

#### Update

Since you will be having plaintext passwords going over the wire (assuming this service is reachable from the network), I recommend permitting authentication only over an encrypted line. The configuration I'm going to show will still accept mails for which the server is the destination without authentication. As far as I know, that behaviour is mandated by an RFC for SMTP servers which are reachable from the internet.

Announce SASL authentication only over encrypted connections

```
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
```

Don't require everyone to talk to you over an encrypted channel

```
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
```

SASL boilerplate

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
```

For whom to accept mail. This is worked left to right, until a permitting or denying rule is encountered. Fallback behaviour would be to permit.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_auth_destination, reject_plaintext_session, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

- `permit_auth_destination` as first rule would make sure that clients may deliver mail to users for which I feel responsible unauthenticated. The clients may choose whether to use TLS or not.
- `reject_plaintext_session` as second rule makes sure that all other rules further down the line can assume an ecrypted channel.
- `permit_sasl_authenticated` is self-explanatory
- `reject` as last rule basically changes the default policy to "deny".

If you don't want to accept mails without SMTP authentication, you may want to drop the first rule of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

Not shown is the configuration of the SSL certificate and how to tell postfix about it (the latter of which is easy).

Comment: I don't have `dovecot`, but I just noticed you can have it verify SASL auth. via an SQL query using Cyrus: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#auxprop_sql, That's pretty much all I'd need for the authentication. Do you have any comments regarding this?

Comment: If it has the features you require, then that will be fine. I have updated my original answer with some security considerations. (I had to resort to `dovecot` since I wanted to use Kerberos and `postfix` + SASL did not seem to be able to make that work.)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'll play with that and see what I can do.